# Future underground electrical supply

Tags: electrical, landscaping, underground

We are about to start on a phased plan to landscape our back yard. Phase one calls for a driveway to be poured behind our house, which will cross the entire property and connect two shared driveways on either side of our home.

Phase two involves adding a tiny house/office on the back of our lot which will need utilities including electrical.

I have no idea what our electrical needs will be, nor do I know the exact location of the structure.

What is the best way to prepare for an eventual electrical supply, given that it will need to run under the new driveway? Should I bury conduit without a cable, maybe with rope inside of it to pull cable in the future? Or should I go ahead and run cable through the conduit and terminate it in a box underground for future connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely run the largest conduit you can obtain across the driveway. Possibly two or three or four parallel runs -- you don't know if you will eventually want to use one for low-voltage cabling, another to pass a water pipe through, etc. PVC conduit holds up very well underground and is relatively cheap even in large diameters.

You can put conduit underneath the driveway and terminate it 10' away on both sides of it. Plug the ends with putty or something else removable, and you can reduce the conduit size to whatever size you actually need in the future when it comes time to do the installation.

For such a short length of conduit, I wouldn't worry about a pull cable. You can easily run a fish tape 15-30 ft.

Comment: Good thoughts. I guess even if I use a direct-bury cable i can still fish it thru the conduit...

Comment: You'd have to come to the surface to do that, though.  You'll thank yourself later to lay 2-3 hefty conduits the whole way.   Is water/sewer realistic there?  It's not the water that's hard, it's the sewer.

Comment: @Harper I wouldn't come to the surface. I would just put a pin in the ground (rebar works and is cheap) to mark the spot, and leave the conduit buried underground. When he's ready to use it, he can dig it back up.

Comment: I might just run it the whole way to the back of the lot (or close to it) and do the rebar pin thing.

Comment: I am planning on going ahead and running sewer to the current exterior cleanout. Fortunately our whole lot slopes slightly toward the street, so pitch is easy with the sewer.

Comment: @andrewniesen The advantage to the short length is that you don't know what your future amperage needs will be. You probably can't/don't want to spend the money on a long run of, say, 4" diameter PVC. On the other hand, 20 feet of it is easily cost effective. You can then later determine (when you build) what amperage you desire and run it that way.

Comment: @andrewniesen Not to mention, direct burial cable is substantially cheaper if you decide not to go with a full length conduit run. Its partially cheaper because its solid, not stranded, cable. Pulling direct burial solid wire through a conduit will be a painful task, but running it through 20' of super wide diameter conduit won't be so bad.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer true, that.   Just keep in mind you can't put power in the same conduit as anything else, so you need at the very least 2.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer -- conduit is quite cheap compared to the costs of digging things back up later because you need to go back and put more/fatter wires in

Comment: @Harper You can in fact run low-voltage wires in the same conduit as long as they are rated for line voltage. I don't think I've ever seen wires that don't fit into that -- CAT6 for example is routinely hi-pot certified to 600V. The code reference is NEC 300.3(C)(1). Whether or not you'd want to do this is a different question, because the line voltage wires will induce noise on the low voltage wiring. Its probably fine if the wires are shielded, though. YMMV, I still wouldn't do it.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The problem there is you're assuming the conduit will be large enough. I think of conduit as insurance in case the wires go bad somehow, plus better protection from underground animals. I don't think of it much as future proofing.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer -- why would you put a wimpy little half-inch conduit in?  You'd want the fat conduit down there to begin with to save you a call to the electrician and their truck o' pullin' tools...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Who said anything about a half-inch conduit? Would you plan on putting in 3" conduit to handle 400 amp service to the office, or perhaps even 4" to make pulling easier, "just in case?" Because if not, then we're talking about still choosing a reasonable size conduit and a reasonable size gauge wire.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer -- I'd put the 3" or 4" in based on pulling concerns *alone* -- the cost of underground wiring is mostly the cost of the earthwork